# Extracting text in between certain text/tags in python

Tags: python, string, nlp

So let's say I have a piece of text:
Note: this is a file I'm reading in so it isn't actually commented out in the code

```
" ## BATTERY LIFE: Pretty medicore at 12 hours, the Creative, iAudio, Rio, and iRiver players last longer. 
CUSTOMER SERVICE[-3]## CUSTOMER SERVICE: Awful. Listen to this one, remember the battery statement I made earlier. 
##If your battery dies and it's still under warranty, guess what, you're out of luck, because Apple doesn't cover the battery in the iPod warranty. 
##They have the nerve to charge you $30 for a warrantied iPod.
technical service[-3]## "
```

And I want to extract the elements just before the square brackets, for example, in this piece of text I would like: CUSTOMER SERVICE[-3] and technical service[-3]

Is there any cool way to got about doing this (using some application of Regex) because I'm stumped at the moment.

Comment: what are the possible values for number mentioned under square bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressed in regex way.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mWsAHf/1

Pattern: `\w+ \w+\[-?\d+]`

Comment: what about If i just want the numbers inside each of the square brackets

Comment: Group statement will help you here. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/DhjZ3F/1